# not able to get jquery visible plugin to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to detect whether my $('.credits') element is in view. I'm using the visible plugin (https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-visible/), which looks straightforward, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

html:

```
<div class="picture full" id='peoplestart'>
    <img src="img/People/People_1.JPG" />
    <div class="text" id="people1text">
        <div class="texthead" id="people1head"><span class="kicker">THE</span><br /><span class="big">PEOPLE</span></div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="picture full">
    <img src="img/People/People_2.JPG" />
    <div class="text" id="people2text">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="credits">
    (credits here )
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var visible = $('.credits').visible( true );
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
        if (visible) {
        // The element is visible, do something
            console.log('visible');
        } 
    });

});
```

I'm a little baffled. This must be a simple thing I'm not doing. Anyone know what I've done wrong?

Comment: Open the console and see what errors you get.

Comment: No errors in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right, you wish to know if credits are visible each time scroll event appears. If so, you need to call `visible()` method each time event appears. Simply update your script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
        if ($('.credits').visible(true)) {
        // The element is visible, do something
            console.log('visible');
        } 
    });
});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q1x78zww/).